# Using While condition inside of Thread's run() method

Tags: python, pyqt

I am not sure if `while True:` condition specified inside of `run()` method is necessarily. 
I've executed this code with and without `while` condition and it works fine.
But I still would like to know the purpose of using it. Any ideas why it should or should not be used?

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
import Queue as queue

app = QtGui.QApplication([])
theQueue = queue.Queue()

class TheThread(QtCore.QThread):
    def __init__(self, theQueue, parent=None):
        QtCore.QThread.__init__(self, parent)
        self.theQueue = theQueue

    def run(self):
        while True:
            task = self.theQueue.get()
            self.sleep(1) 
            self.theQueue.task_done()

threads=[]
for i in range(1, 3): 
    thread = TheThread(theQueue)
    threads.append(thread)
    thread.start()

for i in range(len(threads)):
    theQueue.put(i)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `while True` loop means that your thread will continue to run forever (in theory), blocking on the `task = self.theQueue.get()` call. If you were using `threading.Thread` objects, this would make your program hang and fail to exit, because Python threads will keep the main thread alive as long as they're running, unless you set the `daemon` attribute to True prior to starting the thread. However, because you're using QThreads, the program will exit while the threads are still running. You'll end up getting a warning when you do this though:

```
QThread: Destroyed while thread is still running
QThread: Destroyed while thread is still running
```

I would recommend *not* using a `while True` loop, since your threads are only designed to get a single message from the main thread, and call `wait` (similar to `threading.Thread.join`) on each thread object before exiting your main program, to ensure they complete prior to the main thread exiting:

```
class TheThread(QtCore.QThread):
    def __init__(self, theQueue, parent=None):
        QtCore.QThread.__init__(self, parent)
        self.theQueue = theQueue

    def run(self):
        task = self.theQueue.get()
        self.sleep(1) 
        print(task)
        self.theQueue.task_done()

threads=[]
for i in range(1, 3): 
    thread = TheThread(theQueue)
    threads.append(thread)
    thread.start()

for i in range(len(threads)):
    theQueue.put(i)

for t in threads:
    t.wait()
```

If you do need the `while True` loop for some reason, use a sentinel to signal to the threads that they should exit:

```
class TheThread(QtCore.QThread):
    def __init__(self, theQueue, parent=None):
        QtCore.QThread.__init__(self, parent)
        self.theQueue = theQueue

    def run(self):
        for task in iter(self.theQueue.get, None): # None means time to exit
            self.sleep(1) 
            print(task)
            self.theQueue.task_done()
        self.theQueue.task_done()

threads=[]
for i in range(1, 3): 
    thread = TheThread(theQueue)
    threads.append(thread)
    thread.start()

for i in range(len(threads)):
    theQueue.put(i)

# Time to quit
for t in threads:
    theQueue.put(None)

for t in threads:
    t.wait()
```

Comment: Thanks Dano for the detailed explanation! I also learned about `sentinel` from reading your answer! Thanks again!